# How to convert any file as OLEObject binary for word document

Tags: node.js, ms-word, binaryfiles, createoleobject, ole-object

First I will rename the docx to zip file so i can access the files of the documents

[image]
[image]

My goal is to change this oleObject directly (using other file like msg/eml), then I will convert back again to docx.

I've been searching all over the net on how to convert any file to this kind of binary.

Thanks

I tried renaming the file directly as `.bin` but it doesnt work.

I tried also converting the file to buffer and buffer string write as file but still i cant open the file inside the word document

Comment: I find the npm package win32ole for nodejs and it seems this is thing i am looking for. need to create a document then attach the file and it will create the bin file then get the bin file from the newly created doc and replace it to the original document.

My only problem is this npm package uses phyton that is very limited to our server